# Join lines using sed

Tags: sed, echo, terraform

I am trying to provision the file "../ansible-provision/test" with the list of IPs that are stored in the Terraform list: `aws_instance.masters.*.private_ip`

I just try using "echo" and it works, like in the next example:

```
command =  "echo \"${join(" ", aws_instance.masters.*.private_ip)}\" >> ../ansible-provision/test"
```

In the previous example, "echo" writes the IPs of `aws_instance.masters` to the file `../ansible-provision/test` separated by comma.

I would like to do the same but using `sed` instead of using `echo`.

The reason why I want to use `sed` is because I can write that IPs in a specific line.

I tried to use the next sed command, but it only writes the first IP, so I would need to JOIN all the IPs of that object, like I do in the echo command.

```
  command =  "sed -i '3s/.*/terraform working ${aws_instance.masters.0.private_ip}/g' ../ansible-provision/test"
```

Comment: What would you like to do?

Comment: I would like to write the echo  command using sed @Michal

Comment: @AsierGomez, why you want to write `echo` command? when you could read files or inputs from `sed`? Kindly post your question with more details probably you could let us know what you are trying to do on little bit more inside we could help more on same then.

Comment: @Asier Gomez: It would be great if you could formulate your question perhaps like 'I have a number of files with name following pattern aws_instance.masters.*.private_ip and I would like to join them according to....'. That is, that you formulate what are you trying to achieve and do not let us to decipher your join / echo examples.

Comment: Sorry @RavinderSingh13 I am trying to read some IPs from Terraform and writing it to a file. I just try it with "echo" and it works fine, I can do a JOIN so I can have 10.0.0.1 10.0.0.2..., But I don't know how to do that JOIN with "sed".

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 You can check the question again, I think it is more understandable.

Comment: @Michal You can check the question again, I think it is more understandable.

Comment: Thanks for re-wording the question. Yes, it got better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved Joining the List of IPs into a String separated by comma and then writting the line to the file:

```
  command =  "sed -i '3s/.*/terraform working ${join(" ", aws_instance.masters.*.private_ip)}/g' ../ansible-provision/test"
```